# How does the prefix 'entre' in French's 'entreprendre' compare with the prefix 'under-' in English's 'undertake'?

Tags: english, etymology, french, prefixes

> [enterprise (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=enterprise&searchmode=none)
> early 15c., "an undertaking," formerly also *enterprize*, from Old French *enterprise* "an undertaking," noun use of fem. past participle of ***entreprendre*** "**UNDERtake**, take in hand" (12c.), from ***entre-* "between"** (see [entre-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=entre-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + *prendre* "to take," contraction of *prehendere* (see [prehensile](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=prehensile&allowed_in_frame=0)). Abstract sense of "adventurous disposition, readiness to undertake challenges, spirit of daring" is from late 15c.

I heed the Etymological Fallacy, but [how should the etymology be interpreted, to connect the prefixes 'entre-' with 'under-'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205571/how-does-be-of-combine-to-mean-possess-give-rise-to#comment485482_205571) .

`Update on 2015 Dec 4:` I might have answered my own question. [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/61189/50720) references
pp 210-214, *An Analytic Dictionary of English Etymology, An Introduction* (2008) by Anatoly Liberman that explicate 'under-' in 'understand',
which is summarised [here](http://mentalfloss.com/article/66321/what-does-understand-have-do-standing-under) whose final 2 paragraphs recapitulate Etymonline below (which I failed to scrutinise):

> [[under (prep., adv.)]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=under&allowed_in_frame=0) Also used in Old English as a preposition meaning "between, among," (though this may be an entirely separate root; see [understand](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=understand&allowed_in_frame=0)).
>
> [...] the *under* is not the usual word meaning "beneath," but from Old English *under*, from PIE **nter-* "between, among"
> [...]
> That is the suggestion in Barnhart, but other sources regard the "among, between, before, in the presence of" sense of Old English prefix and preposition under as other meanings of the same word. "Among" seems to be the sense in many Old English compounds [...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How did entre- "between" evolve to mean UNDER in UNDERtake?

It didn't. English used one prefix to derive this meaning from the more general root for taking; French used another. You can turn it around and ask, from a French speaker's perspective, how the English *under* "sous, sou-" evolved to mean "entre". While we're at it, Russian formed its word for undertaking by adding the equivalent of "fore-" or "pre-" to the equivalent of "receive" or "accept". The starting point may be more or less the same ("take"), the end point may also be the same ("undertake"), but individual languages simply took different paths to get from one to the other. I don't see a reason to use any specific version as a semantic standard.

Answer (score 3):

You are not wrong; German *unter* and Latin *inter* are actually related.  See for instance [wiktionary PGm entry for ***under***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Germanic/under):

> **Etymology**. From a merger of two originally distinct suffixes as a result of
>   Verner's law: Proto-Indo-European ***n̥tér** ‎(“inside”), **from which also
>   Latin *inter***, and Proto-Indo-European ***n̥dʰér** ‎(“under”), from which
>   Latin īnfrā, Sanskrit अध ‎(adha, “below”) and Ossetian дæлæ ‎(dælæ,
>   “below”).

This explains why in OE, *under* had both the meaning of "beneath" and that of "amongst/between".  Only the former acceptation subsists today.

As an aside note regarding the latter meaning of "between", you can have a look at de Vaan 2008 *inter* (many cognates meaning "entrails" in many languages - gory).

The prefix *under* in *under*take is to compare to *unter* in *unter*nehmen ("undertake" in Present Day German) - since "nehmen" means "to take".

And as a matter of fact, before switching to "undertaken" in Middle English, Old English had *undernimen*.  But then, during Middle English, *taken* displaced OE *niman* - IMO under the influence of Old Norse. *Undernimen* was therefore logically replaced by *undertaken*.  Also note that, in its other meaning of "understand", *undernimen* also disappeared and only *understandan* remained as PDE *understand*.

French *entre* is, as you well know, a direct descendent of Latin *inter*.

Romance languages use *inter* or *in* <sup>1</sup>. Italian has both *imprendere*/*intrapendere* - as you know *prendere* is *to take*.  Also Spanish has *emprender*; Portuguese has *interprender*.

You have a similar phenomenon with *underwritan* ("underwrite") and *unterschreiben*).  But this time, German takes *schreiben* from Latin *scribo* and English sticks with  PGm *writana.  See *subscribe*.

Also worth mentioning is *entertain* (cognate with French *entre-tenir* etc); to compare with German *unterhalten* (*halten* = to hold/tenir).  This time there was no OE equivalent for *entertain*, so a Romance loan word was imported.

So to summarise, PDE *undertake* does not come from Anglo-Norman *entreprendre* (mostly "to attack") or even Late Latin *imprehendere*/*interprehendere* ("to assault by surprise", "undertake").  However they do have common traceable PIE roots and there is, as you suggest, a correspondence between *entre* and *under* in a number of cases.

---

(1) Ernout Meillet have an interesting conjecture why Latin uses both *in* and *inter* (see *in*)

Answer (score 1):

The prefix ***entre-*** in *entreprendre* comes from Proto-Indo-European ***e̯enteri*** "between, inside", from ***e̯en*** "in", the prefix ***under-*** in *undertaking* comes from PIE ***ndheri*** meaning "under".

Comment: Given that [there is no direct evidence of PIE, and no evidence suggesting it was ever written](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language), I think you need to give a bit more supporting evidence for this claim.

Comment: @FumbleFingers there is a lot of evidence of PIE. It was never written, of course. LOL.

Comment: I'm not questioning the *existence* of PIE. Simply suggesting that if you want to resolve OP's uncertainty, it would be helpful if you could show some evidence (or plausible speculation) for how ***e̯enteri*** and ***ndheri*** actually led (through their separate pathways) to ***entreprendre*** and ***undertaking***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. The best evidence is Latin inter vs infra, which represent two different IE roots, one with *t and the other with *dh.

Comment: @fdb by the way, Russian недра could not be from nedhra̯ ?